# Extract the report of Room Calendar from exchage server using powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

we are having around 90 rooms mailbox in exchange 2010, Now i want to extract the caledar report of rooms in exchage server 2010 using powershell. the report should contain the following details.

a.  Room usage for a week for each specific room (usage is relative to how many hours the room is available for the day)
b.  Room usage for a month for each specific room (usage is relative to how many hours the room is available for the week)
c.  Number of bookings per user
d.  Number of bookings canceled
e.  Number of bookings rescheduled

is there any possibility to get the report with above mentioned points into excel using powershell in exchage server?

if i do export from outlook for room calendar, i can get the report for only one room. and is it possible to get the report of all room calendar?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this..

You need to install Exchange Managed API for it to work.

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Name:impersonationAssignmentName –Role:ApplicationImpersonation –User:serviceAccount
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204095%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx

When running the script you will be prompted for credentials. Be sure to specify the domain (DomainName\UserId)

Alse change the cashub server in the script (or use autodiscovery)

Save as Get-RoomUsage.ps1 optional parameters are -StartDate and -Enddate

```
param 
(

[DateTime]$StartDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-30),
[DateTime]$EndDate = (Get-date)

)

$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox #| select -First 10


$rptcollection = @()

## Load Managed API dll  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"  

## Set Exchange Version  
$ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2  

## Create Exchange Service Object  
$service = New-Object    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)  

## Set Credentials to use two options are availible Option1 to use explict credentials or Option 2 use the Default (logged On) credentials  

#Credentials Option 1 using UPN for the windows Account  
$psCred = Get-Credential  

$creds = New-Object    System.Net.NetworkCredential($psCred.GetNetworkCredential().username.ToString(),$psCred.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString(),$psCred.GetNetworkCredential().domain.ToString())  
$service.Credentials = $creds   


#Credentials Option 2  
#$service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  

## Choose to ignore any SSL Warning issues caused by Self Signed Certificates  

## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
## Create a compilation environment
$Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
$Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
$Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
$Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
$Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
$Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
$Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

$TASource=@'
  namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
    public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
      public TrustAll() { 
      }
      public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, 
        System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
'@ 
$TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
$TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
$TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

## end code from http://poshcode.org/624

## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server) to use two options are availbe to use Autodiscover to find the CAS URL or Hardcode the CAS to use  

#CAS URL Option 1 Autodiscover  
#$service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})  
#"Using CAS Server : " + $Service.url   

#CAS URL Option 2 Hardcoded  

$uri=[system.URI] "https://cashubserver/ews/exchange.asmx"  
$service.Url = $uri    

$obj = @{}
$start = Get-Date 
$i = 0
foreach($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{
$i +=1
$Duration = (New-TimeSpan -Start ($start) -End (Get-Date)).totalseconds
$TimeLeft = ($Duration/$i)*($mailboxes.count - $i)
Write-Progress -Status "$($Mailbox.DisplayName)" -Activity "Mailbox $i of $($Mailboxes.Count)" -PercentComplete ($i/$($mailboxes.count)*100) -SecondsRemaining $timeleft -Id 100


$WorkingDays = ($Mailbox | Get-mailboxCalendarConfiguration).WorkDays.ToString()
$WorkingHoursStartTime = ($Mailbox |    Get-mailboxCalendarConfiguration).WorkingHoursStartTime
$WorkingHoursEndTime = ($Mailbox | Get-mailboxCalendarConfiguration).WorkingHoursEndTime

if($WorkingDays -eq "Weekdays"){$WorkingDays = "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday"}
if($WorkingDays -eq "AllDays"){$WorkingDays = "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday"}
if($WorkingDays -eq "WeekEndDays"){$WorkingDays = "Saturday,Sunday"}

## Optional section for Exchange Impersonation  
$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $Mailbox.PrimarySMTPAddress) 

$folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnown    FolderName]::Calendar,$Mailbox.PrimarySMTPAddress.tostring())   
$Calendar = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($Service,$folderid)

if($Calendar.TotalCount -gt 0){
    $cvCalendarview = new-object    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarView($StartDate,$EndDate,2000)
$cvCalendarview.PropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)

$frCalendarResult = $Calendar.FindAppointments($cvCalendarview)
$inPolicy = New-TimeSpan
$OutOfPolicy = New-TimeSpan
$TotalDuration = New-timespan
$BookableTime = New-TimeSpan
$c = 0
foreach ($apApointment in $frCalendarResult.Items){
     $c +=1
     Write-Progress -Status "$($Mailbox.DisplayName)" -Activity "Mailbox $i of $($Mailboxes.Count)" -PercentComplete ($i/$($mailboxes.count)*100) -SecondsRemaining $timeleft -Id 100 -CurrentOperation "Processing calendarItem $c or $($frCalendarResult.Items.count)"
     $psPropset = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
     $apApointment.load($psPropset)
     if($apApointment.IsAllDayEvent -eq $false)
     {

         if($apApointment.Duration)
         {
                if($WorkingDays.split(",") -contains ($apApointment.start).dayofweek)
                {
                    $TotalDuration = $TotalDuration.add((new-timespan -End $apApointment.End.tolongTimeString() -start $apApointment.start.tolongTimeString()))

                    #Only count to inPolicy if within the workinghours time
                    if($apApointment.start.tolongTimeString() -lt $WorkingHoursStartTime)
                    {   
                        $tStart = $WorkingHoursStartTime.ToString()
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        $tStart = $apApointment.start.ToLongTimeString()
                    }

                    if($apApointment.End.tolongTimeString() -gt $WorkingHoursEndTime)
                    {   
                        $tEnd = $WorkingHoursEndTime.ToString()
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        $tEnd = $apApointment.End.ToLongTimeString()

                    }

                    $Duration = New-TimeSpan -Start $tStart -End $tEnd
                    $inPolicy = $inPolicy.add($Duration)
                }
            }
     }

}

#Calculate to total hours of bookable time between the 2 dates
for ($d=$Startdate;$d -le $Enddate;$d=$d.AddDays(1)){
  if ($WorkingDays.split(",") -contains $d.DayOfWeek) 
  {
    $BookableTime += $WorkingHoursEndTime - $WorkingHoursStartTime

  }
  } #for

#Save result....
$rptobj = "" | Select samAccountName,DisplayName,inPolicy,Out-Of-Policy,TotalDuration,BookableTime,BookedPersentage
$rptobj.samAccountName = $Mailbox.samAccountName
$rptobj.DisplayName = $Mailbox.DisplayName
$rptobj.inPolicy =  '{0:f2}' -f ($inPolicy.TotalHours)
$rptobj."Out-Of-Policy" =  '{0:f2}' -f (($TotalDuration - $inPolicy).TotalHours)
$rptobj.TotalDuration =  '{0:f2}' -f ($TotalDuration.TotalHours)
$rptobj.BookableTime =  '{0:f2}' -f ($BookableTime.TotalHours)
$rptobj.BookedPersentage =  '{0:f2}' -f (($inPolicy.TotalHours / $BookableTime.TotalHours) * 100)
$rptcollection += $rptobj

} #ForEach
}

$rptcollection
```

It will output something like this.

```
samAccountName   : room1
DisplayName      : Room Mailbox 1
inPolicy         : 98,50
Out-Of-Policy    : 2,75
TotalDuration    : 101,25
BookableTime     : 207,00
BookedPersentage : 47,58

samAccountName   : room2
DisplayName      : Room Mailbox 2
inPolicy         : 35,92
Out-Of-Policy    : 0,00
TotalDuration    : 35,92
BookableTime     : 207,00
BookedPersentage : 17,35
```

Comment: wow, Thank you so much... am very sorry for late reply... the thing is we couldnt able install EWS in our organisation as we are getting support from MS. So we have a restricted access. is there any way to get it from BPOS without EWS?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `ManagementRoleAssignment` for your user?

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Name:impersonationAssignmentName –Role:ApplicationImpersonation –User:serviceAccount
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this tripped up anyone else but there are spaces in a spot that shouldn't have them. My copy paste of the following line contained spaces between WellKnow and FolderName

> $folderid = new-object
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnown
>   FolderName]::Calendar,$Mailbox.PrimarySMTPAddress.tostring())